# Nativescript environment value getting either Boolean or undefined.

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Whenever I try to run the build as below, I get the environment value as Boolearn or undefined, not the actual value of the environment. Anyone find that how to take the value instead of boolean value.

**Command to run the build**

```
tns build android --bundle --env.url="xxxxxxxx"
{"url":true,"android":true}
```

I have referred native script's forum, where no one replied. For your refernece, find the below url.

[Native script forum URL](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/environment-flags-prod-or-env/4365/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of CLI you are using? It was a known issue in 3.x, values will be only passed as boolean. Since 4.x, the issue was resolved and accepts string values too.